# Rendered model is skewed and out of shape

Tags: modeling, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I've just started creating the model of a Carom board and it looks fine in the perspective, orthographic views. But, when I render the same it gets skewed up and looks very odd. Am I missing something here?

When "Rendered" is selected, it looks different.
[image: Looks different (skewed) in rendered view.]

Blend file:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the render's Aspect Ratio set to 3:2

[image]

resetting them to the default 1:1 will fix your issue

Comment: Thanks, this worked, This must have changed when I selected a different profile in the Dimensions > Render Presets..